# How to specify, which resource file to be used while running?

Tags: java, properties, localization, resourcebundle

I wants my application to be in both Hindi and English language, so I have created a ResourceBundle named as Resources. In this directory I have create label.properties,label_en_US.properties and label_hi_IN.properties and these file have putted some values like ab=xy_default, ab=xy_in_en and ab=xy_in_hindi respectively.
 [image]

And Now I planned to use them as label text, so in property of that label i mantioned the default one, like this[image] 
Here code is key and In label_defualt is `code=Code :` , in label_en_US `code=Code :` and in label_hi_IN `code=कोड :`. How can I specify which of label.properties to be useout of label, label_en_US or label_hi_in. I have stored user preference in my database like which language to use. 
 I want to know how I can force or tell it use that particular file out of label, label_en_US, label_hi_IN in main function or somewhere else. 
**As now it's taking values from label.properties file only, if user want it to be in hindi then how internally we force to use that label_hi_IN.properties file.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it, We have to just set Default Locale.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("hi","IN");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got your files sorted out OK, the right internationalization should occur naturally depending on your locale. If you want to test other supported locales in your software, set the appropriate system properties:

```
java -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=hi …
```

or

```
java -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en …
```

Comment: Like I am in India then it suppose to pickup label_hi_IN, but It's not picking up that. When I run the application in IDE. It keep only that which mentioned while setting label text e.g. in description of Question I have mantioned ...label.code in image. It sets that value of label_text to the value from `label.properties` not from `label_hi_IN.properties`.

Comment: How and Where I can set this properties `java -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=hi`. @g00se

Comment: In the run command. How will you run your app?

Comment: I am running it by run button in Netbeans IDE.
Like I have language option in UI, here to we can change the language. So I want it work according to selected language. @g00se

Comment: Don't concern yourself with Netbeans. That's for *developing* programs, not for running them, though there are probably run configurations you can use (to run *while* developing) to set the system properties I mentioned. You should though get used to running your apps outside of your development environment

Answer (score 0):

ResourceBundle uses a “fallback” strategy.  If the user’s current locale is hi-IN:

- ResourceBundle.getBundle will look in label_hi_IN.properties (if that resource exists)
- If that file is not found, ResourceBundle.getBundle will look for label_hi.properties (if that resource exists)
- If that file is not found, ResourceBundle.getBundle will look for label.properties (if that resource exists)

This means you should do the following:

- If label.properties contains English entries, remove label_en_US.properties from your project
- If label.properties contains Hindi entries, remove label_hi_IN.properties from your project
- Rename label_hi_IN.properties, if it is still present, to label_hi.properties, so all Hindi locales will use that file
- Rename label_en_US.properties, if it is still present, to label_en.properties, so all English locales will use that file

Comment: I have an configuration menu to which user can select a language either of Hindi or English while application running. So I want application use the Resource bundle according to the selected language. If Hindi is selected by user the it use label_hi.properties otherwise it use the label.properties. Ultimately I mean to say that how programmatic enforce to use that particular resource file like if hindi is preference of user then it use the label_hi instead of label.properties.

Comment: There are many `getBundle` methods in ResourceBundle.  You need to call one of the `getBundle` methods which takes a Locale argument, like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)).

Comment: According to you we can use `Locale locale = new Locale("hi","IN");
        ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/Resources/label",locale);
        String str = resource.getString("code");` This will work when we are setting label one by one in java `lbl.setText(str);`, But If I have set this text in property of JLabel itself(Like I have mentioned in second image in question itself). then how it will get know which resource bundle to use? it will use only which in mentioned while assignment time for above label.properties not the label_hi_IN.properties. Then how?

Comment: `locale` should not be a local variable.  It should be an instance field in your class.  Each of your menu items’ Actions or ActionListeners should update that field.